# Can't enable sites in VPS

Tags: apache-2.2

I had an incompatibility problem with `mysql-server` that caused my VPS to fall over. I put it in technical support hands. Now, technical support tells me that my document root is not configured correctly because only points to `/var/www`.
But I didn't change anything of my apache configuration! I have a default file in `/etc/apache2/sites-avaiable` with the next code:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ErrorDocument 404 /error404.html
    ErrorDocument 403 /error403.html

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /var/www
    <Directory />
            Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes
            AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/>
            Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
            AllowOverride all
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        LogLevel warn
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

And the two sites in the same path (`itransformer.es` and `msalsas.com`) have the next code:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.itransformer.es
    ServerAlias itransformer.es *.itransformer.es
    DocumentRoot /var/www/itransformer/web
</VirtualHost>
```

and

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName msalsas.com
    ServerAlias www.msalsas.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/msalsas
    <Directory /var/www/msalsas>
       AllowOverride all
       Options all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Before I did:

```
a2ensite itransformer.es
```

and it worked for me. Now, it tells me:

```
ERROR: Site itransformer.es does not exist!
```

Any idea of what can be happening here?

I have tried to link to sites-enabled by:

```
ln -s /etc/apache2/sites-available/itransformer.es /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/itransformer.es
```

But it's not the problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try adding a "directory section" in itransformer.es virtual host definition. judging from the snippets of config you posted it have been left away.
try this.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.itransformer.es
    ServerAlias itransformer.es *.itransformer.es
    DocumentRoot /var/www/itransformer/web

    <Directory /var/www/itransformer/web>
       AllowOverride all
       Options all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: It doesn't solve the issue

Comment: have a look to your apache2.conf. some distros use
`IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf`
or 
`Include sites-enabled/*.conf`
this will lead to apache2 not accepting virtualhost files not ending with **.conf** suffix
a simila issue was crossposted here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10557770/adding-subdomain-to-apache2-with-a2ensite-causes-error-error-site-domain-com-d)

Comment: Yes! That's it! I've put my site files to itransformer.conf and msalsas.conf and it works again. Thank you